# RadGrid displays value twice (duplicate) in a row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, duplicate-data

Telerik's RadGrid displays value twice, if `GridTemplateColumn` has `UniqueName` attribute and `<ItemTemplate>` tag.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="Name">
    <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Name") %></ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Width="100%" MaxLength="256" /></EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

If I remove `ItemTemplate` tag, it displays the value just once, but I would like to format the value conditionally, for which I think I need `ItemTemplate` tag as I dont want to update my object's property (in this case, `Name`) itself.

I need `UniqueName` attribute as its used in NestedHierarchy tables. How do I keep control over the display value and display it just once?

One more problem with having `ItemTemplate` tag is, the Expand/Collapse buttons are not present in the grid. I want them to be present.

[image: Duplicate values showed in same row]

Comment: why not you filter it in backEnd or in Dataview ???

Comment: @Ravi: I dont want the actual value changed. For example, in the above table, I would like to display "Blue Blood special" using ItemTemplate. But on edit, the EditTemplate should show "Blue Blood" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the column on item data bind event `RadGrid1_ItemDataBound`.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item is GridDataItem && !e.Item.IsInEditMode)
     {
         var dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
         var dto = (yourDto)e.Item.DataItem;
         dataBoundItem["Name"] = dto.Name + " special";
     }
}
```